# JavaScript counter with closure and IIFE

Tags: javascript, closures, counter, iife

On www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp there is a basic example of a counter in a closure, and as far as I can tell, an IIFE:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    console.log(counter);
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// the counter is now 3
```

However, after hours of reading on scope, closures and IIFEs, not for the first time, and looking at other simple examples, I still don't understand why the `var counter = 0;` line is only executed once. The console log I added right after that line never outputs anything, as if it never gets called.

Why is the counter not reset at 0 every time add() is called? What concept(s) am I understanding wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The function is immediately invoked so `counter` initialization only happens once. Now, `add` is the returned function, which just increments `counter`.

Comment: `var add` is not referencing the outer function that comes after the `=`; it's referencing the one that is returned by `return function() { ... }`, so that's the one you're invoking when you do `add()`.

Comment: The `console.log` line *does* output `0` for me before the first `add()` call?

Comment: @Bergi that is because it is an IIFE invoked at the time of initialization - aka before first add();

Comment: @rabbitco Yes, exactly, but the OP claims "*that line never outputs anything*"

Comment: @AndrewLi : So it's as if the first pass (`var add = (...)()`) only 'builds' the function add and initializes counter, and only subsequent calls to add() go inside the function add()?

Comment: @Hiroshima, is there anything unclear in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40091513/2545680)?

Comment: @Maximus: I just found rabbitco 's answer clearer and my console log didn't even output 0 one single time. But yeah, naming functions is a good idea to check under the hood.

Comment: @Hiroshima, no problem, but it should output 0 once. This is certain. Run your code in console and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step for the Javascript engine (after declaring `add`) is to initialize `add` which results in an invocation of the IIFE which again results in:

```
var add = function () {

    return counter = counter++
}
```

because the IIFE returns this function as the value to be assigned to `add`. The function assigned to `add` still has access to the lexical scope of the IIFE (`var counter`): that is closure.

Each `add()` is an invocation of the function returned from the IIFE and therefore `var counter = 0` is only invocated once (at the time of initializing `add`).

Answer (score 2):

> I still don't understand why the var counter = 0; line is only
>   executed once.

Because the IIFE function is invoked only once. The `add()` calls execute this function:

```
function () {return counter += 1;}
```

which is returned from the IIFE. You can check that by giving functions names and inspecting the name of the function being executed:

```
var add = (function iife() {
    var counter = 0;
    console.log(counter);
    return function inner() {return counter += 1;}
})();

add.name; // `inner`, not `iife`
```

> The console log I added right after that line never outputs anything,
>   as if it never gets called

It can't be. It should output `0` just once.